# Permission denied creating database SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am new to SQL Server and facing a problem of creating new database in SQL Server 2008 R2. I found a solution on the internet but i have little confusing while setting some paramter.

Here is the solution :

1. Type `services.msc` in Run
2. Shut down SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) from services. Note the exe path.
3. Open cmd window (run as admin) and run single-user mode as local admin with this command (the path is from the previous step):

   ```
   c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.2\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe" -m -s SQLEXPRESS
   ```
4. Open another cmd window (run as admin).
5. Type the following `sqlcmd`:

   ```
   sqlcmd -S .\SQLEXPRESS
   ```

   In the prompt, type:

   ```
   1> sp_addsrvrolemember '<domain\user>', 'sysadmin'
   2> GO
   ```
6. Close both cmd windows.

When I try to run this :

```
sp_addsrvrolemember '<domain\user>', 'sysadmin'
```

I got

> is not a valid login or you don't have permission.

I don't know what is `<domain\user>`. And my windows user is administrator, currently logged in as administrator.